# Trigger AWS CloudWatch alarm when a boolean value is changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to create an AWS CloudWatch alarm/event which is triggered when a boolean value is changed from 1 to 0, or from 0 to 1. e.g. SaveInProgress of ElasticCache. How can create it?

My understanding is: the current AWS CloudWatch alarm can only be triggered if a threshold is larger than, less than, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue. I solved it using Metric Math. So I gave my metric an ID (say, foo), then had a Metric Math expression based off that with the following functions: `ABS(RATE(foo))`

By then setting the threshold to Greater than zero, you can end up with an alarm which will trigger every time the underlying metric changes.

Docs on using Metric Math in alarms - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create-alarm-on-metric-math-expression.html

Comment: Thanks bagelben! that is a great solution